# Automatically setting the type in the "Log a Call" action on cases?

Tags: case, page-layout, publisher-action

I'm trying to automatically have the type for tasks created by the "Log a Call" action on cases to be set to "Call".

I've already achieved this with custom buttons on objects, and changing the action for the global publisher actions, but I can't seem to find where I can make changes to some of the actions for cases?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last bit of the question. Can you clarify? You can create a custom button to override the 'New' Case button, which has the 'Log a Call' field set to 'Call' via JavaScript. This may help here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hU1hAAE

Comment: Okay so when a you have an existing case, there's an option to show the "Log a Call" Action, along with Answer Customer, Write Case Note, etc.

With the Global Publisher Actions you can change that certain fields default to a specific value. I'm wondering how, if at all this can be accomplished with the action on Case.